# How to sort the time in table using my sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

how to sort the table for time . that is from 6.00 AM t0 10.00 PM

```
 name    source destination time 
 gokul   xxx    yyyy        10.00 PM
 abc     xxx    yyyy        6.00 AM
```

I tried this query in side subquery still not working

```
Select * from (
  Select * from trips where date = '27-09-2013' 
  and time like '%PM' or '%pm' ORDER BY time
) AND (
  Select * from trips where date = '27-09-2013' 
  and time like '%AM' or '%am' ORDER BY time
) AS TIME 
ORDER BY TIME(time) DESC'
```

Comment: is time in string form, with AM and PM?, or in actual timestamp form?

Comment: its a varchar @AdrianBR and i tried ORDER BY and LIKE but its not wokring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tabel_name 
    ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`time`,'%h.%i%p');
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5a93/3) working example.

**EDITED:**

After seeing your query i am posting the modified query for you.

```
SELECT * FROM trips 
    WHERE `date` = '27-09-2013' 
       AND ((`time` like '%PM' OR '%pm') 
          OR (`time` like '%AM' OR '%am')) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`time`,'%h.%i%p') DESC
```

Comment: @gokul can you post your table structure also.